# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First: How is the Discriminator determined?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Currently I have class hierarchy defined with the Code First approach as follows.

[image]

E.F. has autogenerated a nvarchar(128) discriminator. It is not a key field.

How does Entity Framework determine what and what Type the discriminator field should be, and is it always the same, i.e. *nvarchar*? Is the discriminator at all accessible *outside* the database i.e. from LINQ to Entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discriminator column is by default nvarchar because it stores names of your classes to differ between types - that is the whole point of this column: to allow EF knowing what class instance from your inheritance hierarchy it should create when it loads record from the database.

Discriminator column is not accessible by linq-to-entities. It is only used to map record to correct type.

Comment: Then would it be safe to say we can determine the discriminator column value by simply getting the entity instance's Type's Name property?